# How to fix NullPointerException?

Tags: java, class, exception, nullpointerexception, null

I am working on a little project and have big problem.... 
I faced the bad side of NullPointerException in Java 
So here is the code:

```
  Coordinates[] point = new Coordinates[26];
    for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        if (points[i] > 0) {
            char ch = (char) (i + 65);
                point[i].setName(ch);
                point[i].setX(points[i]);
        }
    }
    //Coordinates is class containing 3 fields
    //setName() method just sets Name field
    //setX() method sets X coordinate
```

I want to make point for every letter in alphabet, but I got NullpointerException when I use setName() method.How can I fix it, please help :(

Comment: initialize the array. `point[i]=new Coordinates();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not initializing your `Coordinates` instances, only the `array` holding them.

As a result, invoking any method of `point[i]` throws `NullPointerException` as it points to a `null` `Coordinates`.

You can initialize each `Coordinates` of `point` with a new instance:

```
// some iteration
point[x] = new Coordinates();
```

Or you can fill the `array` with the reference to the same instance (probably not what you want):

```
Arrays.fill(point, new Coordinates());
```

Answer (score 0):

You must instantiate each instance of `Coordinates` before calling its methods.

```
    Coordinates[] point = new Coordinates[26];
    for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) { 
        if (points[i] > 0) {
            char ch = (char) (i + 65);
                point[i] = new Coordinates();
                point[i].setName(ch);
                point[i].setX(points[i]);
        }
    }
```